# Find command on Solaris 9 stopped working

Tags: solaris, ksh

I have seen this command working for a long time:

```
find $dir -name $basename.[0-2][0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-3][0-3][0-3] -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Suddenly, it stopped working.

I have tried to put single quotes `'` between the file names and it worked for few days. And then I used double quotes `"` and it is working now again.

Since I did not find any changes on the system or in the account (both are using the ksh), can you please give a reasonable reason for this stop working with no apparent reason?

Comment: Are there spaces in the filenames?

Answer (score 2):

There should be double quotes around the variables and single quotes around the bracket expansions. The former is to protect spaces, tabs and newlines in filenames. The latter is to delay expansion of the bracket expression so that `find` does it instead of the shell. You might need double quotes around the curly braces to protect white space, too.

```
find "$dir" -name "$basename".'[0-2][0-3][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-3][0-3][0-3]' -exec rm -f "{}" \;
```

The reason it isn't working is likely that a file exists in the *current* directory (not necessarily `$dir`) that matches the bracket expression and causes it to be prematurely expanded.

If the above doesn't work, try it without the quotes around the curly braces.